# Spring File uploading. Require file to be present

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I have simple controller method which receives file:

```
  @ResponseBody
  public MyDto createProduct(MyDto dto, @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) {

  }
```

The problem is that Spring doesn't throw exception if user didn't chose file in form. But I need to be sure that user chose some file. I tried to add `required = true` but it didn't help (moreover is by default set to `true`)

Actually Spring throws exception only if my form doesn't contain parameter named `file` at all:

> Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

But if parameter present and file is not chose in HTML form then there is no exception.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can push your `MultipartFile file` as a property of your DTO and write a custom validation annotation e.g. `@FilePresent`. Your signature would than be something like

```
  public MyDto createProduct(@Validated MyDto dto, BindingResult result)
```

your would annotate your *file* property inside *MyDto*

```
@FilePresent
private MultipartFile file;
```

Your custom validation code would be something like:

*The* `@FilePresent` *annotation*

---

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {FilePresentMultipartFileValidator.class})
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
public @interface FilePresent {

    String message() default "{your.package.FilePresent.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String value() default "true";
}
```

*Custom Validator*

---

```
public class FilePresentMultipartFileValidator implements ConstraintValidator<FilePresent, MultipartFile> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(FilePresent constraintAnnotation) {
        //NOOP
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MultipartFile value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return !(value == null || value.isEmpty());
    }

}
```

the final move is to have a `ValidationMessages.properties` file on the classpath (and/or its localized equivalents) having the key `your.package.FilePresent.message` with the message value you choose